# Equalizing Agent and Master Nagios on state change alone

Tags: nagios

We have a setup where there are distributed Nagios running on multiple sites and are equalizing their data to the main Nagios server. The problem is it sends back the data to main Nagios server no matter if there is a state change in host or service. Is it possible to configure the slave Nagios to check the service/Host every 5 sec but send back the data only if there is a state change.

It is implemented by Obsess Over Hosts/Service which always runs the command which will equalize.

Nagios version is 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by disabling the "obsessive" settings and using an [Event Handler](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/eventhandlers.html) instead.

Create global host/service event handlers to submit passive results (via NSCA) to the master server.

Note that this will make freshness checking on the master Nagios instance completely useless, if you're using this feature.